# GWT on iPhone 4.0 with 3G network

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, gwt, mobile-safari

I have just encountered very strange problem - my GWT app hosted on Google App Engine does not want to work on iPhone over 3G, however it works fine over Wi-Fi.

For testing I created empty GWT module with only Window.alert in the onModuleLoad. If I switch on Wi-Fi, the alert is shown, with 3G - just blank page although with correct title.

Safari Developer console on iPhone looks absolutely the same for 3G and Wi-Fi - some 3 errors about wrong placement of meta tags.

Just recently I installed iPhone OS 4.0 (tried beta 1 and beta 2), and I can not roll it back to version 3, so can not really say where the problem is.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be happening here?

Sample page is hosted on http://iphntst.appspot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a problem neither in iPhone OS 4 nor 3G. Looks like something wrong with Google AppSpot. Now it works well.